# Count entitys dependent om field value and as entity reference

Tags: views, entities

I have two node types, Apartment and Building.

Apartment has two fields:
- "Building" a Entity Reference field that reference to the node type Building
- "Rooms" a Text List with values 1 room, 2 rooms, 3 rooms etc...

I want to have a View, that lists all Buildings and under each Building it displays how many Apartments WITH specific amount of rooms. Like this:

Building 1
1 x 1 room apartment
5 x 2 rooms apartment
6 x 3 rooms apartment

Building 2
7 x 1 room apartment
3 x 2 rooms apartment
2 x 3 rooms apartment

Is this possible to do with Views, and then HOW to do it?

Answer (score 0):

In general [Views Aggregator Plus](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_aggregator) and [Views Calc](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_calc) can both generate tally reports like these.

Unfortuntaley by making `rooms` a `text list` you've basically made it (nearly) impossible for you to easily generate these types of reports. You're question isn't really a Views question, but 1 of how to write a tally report in `SQL`.

Since `rooms` is a simple string, its hard(er) to `SUM` the values to make your report. If the `room` was a `reference` to a `room ID` in another table then SQL, and Views and `aggregation functions` could more easily generate these reports.

> Is this possible to do with Views, and then HOW to do it?

TLDR; Yes, it's possible. It's easier if you make your data into non-string values for aggregation. It's a futile effort to show you how because it's simply too messy in code to work with the data structures you've created.

**EDIT**

If these were numerical numbers for the number of rooms, or room IDs, you could easily use `SUM` aggregation to find the total. Then you would simply use a Views `rewrite substition` to show the output as something like the string `[node-room-sum] x [node-room-size] room(s) aparament` and use tokens derived from your View.

Comment: So if I switch my List (Text) to a Term Reference instead and have a Voc "Rooms" and then terms "1 room", "2 room" etc. It would be better?

Comment: On the docs page for Views Aggragator Plus they show `Enumerations` and `Tallies` and `Sums`. These _may_ work with a list of items as you have, but I've not done it that way ever. I know it will work with references. See the examples on that project page.